# why does my code stay in a loop when i run it

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class PVR {
private:
    int channel;
public:
    PVR() {
        cout << "Select the channel ==> ";
        cin >> channel;
        cout << endl;
    }
};

class DVR  {
private:
    string position;
public:
    DVR() {
        cout << "Select the position ==> ";
        cin >> position;
        cout << endl;
    }
};

class Oven {
private:
    string food;
public:
    Oven() {
        cout << "What do you want to bake? ==> ";
        cin >> food;
        cout << endl;
    }
};


class PrgDevice {
private:
    tm startTime;
    tm stopTime;
    int choice;
    int choice1;
    char c;
public:
    void dateTime() {
        cout << "Enter start date and start time: ";
        cin >> startTime.tm_mday >> startTime.tm_mon >> startTime.tm_year >> startTime.tm_hour >> startTime.tm_min >> startTime.tm_sec;
        cout << "Enter stop date and stop time: ";
        cin >> stopTime.tm_mday >> stopTime.tm_mon >> stopTime.tm_year >> stopTime.tm_hour >> stopTime.tm_min >> stopTime.tm_sec;
    }

    void mainMenu() {
        while (choice != 3) {
            cout << "Main menu options: \n";
            cout << "      1. Select a device to program (contains a submenu)" << endl;
            cout << "      2. Display current status of all devices" << endl;
            cout << "      3. Exit" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your option => ";
            cin >> choice;

            if (choice == 1) {
                subMenu();
            }
            else if (choice == 2) {
                cout << choice;
            }
            else {
            }
        }
    }
    void subMenu() {
        do {
            cout << "Select a device:" << endl;
            cout << "         1. PVR" << endl;
            cout << "         2. Camera DVR" << endl;
            cout << "         3. Oven" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your option => ";
            cin >> choice1;

            if (choice1 == 1) {
                PVR n1;
            }
            else if (choice1 == 2) {
                DVR n2;
            }
            else {
                Oven n3;
            }
            dateTime();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Another device to program Y/N ? => ";

            cin >> c;
        }
        while(c == 'Y' || c == 'y');
    }
};


int main() {
    PrgDevice obj1;
    obj1.mainMenu();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is my output

```
Main menu options: 
      1. Select a device to program (contains a submenu)
      2. Display current status of all devices
      3. Exit
Enter your option => 1
Select a device:
         1. PVR
         2. Camera DVR
         3. Oven
Enter your option => 1
Select the channel ==> 23
Enter start date and start time: 12:01:19 20:00:00
```

when i press enter my program just goes in a loop and i dont know why it does

Comment: You don't initialize your `PrgDevice` member variables, their values will be *indeterminate* and using them will lead to *undefined behavior*. Create a constructor that initializes them.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your programs wants the user to input the time and date as space-separated values, but you input them as colon-separated values.

That means

```
cin >> startTime.tm_mday >> startTime.tm_mon >> ...
```

will read the `12` into `startTime.tm_mday`, but then there is a `:` in the input which doesn't match the type of `startTime.tm_mon`. That will stop all reading of input, leaving the `:` in the input buffer for your next input operation.

The next input operation is for `stopTime` which will fail immediately because of the `:` in the input buffer. So then you're back in the `subMenu` function where the colon will be read into `c`. And `':'` is not equal to `'Y'` or `'y'`, so the loop ends, and the `subMenu` function returns back to `mainMenu` where you print the menu again.

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't feel like an infinite loop to me. Try entering the start time as:

```
12 1 19  20 0 0
```

cin won't magically handle the ':' characters in your input, so you might need to read the entire line, and parse out the ':' chars.